# Conversion of int to double when calling an overloaded function

Tags: c++

```
void essai (int, double); // essai I
void essai (double, int); // essai II

int n, p; double z; char c;

essai(n,z); // calling essai I
essai(c,z); // calling essai I, after the conversion of c in int
essai(n,p); // compilation error
```

Why `essai(n,p)` produce a compilation error here? Is it because the conversion can not be done from int to double?

Comment: What does the compiler say about it?

Comment: This is just theory course notes. There is no function defined in essai. I have an exam tomorrow, and I do not understand why there is a compilation error.

Comment: Ouch... Good luck...

Comment: You can figure this out :) just focus on types given to `essai(n,p)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The compiler looks at the two overloads of `essai` for each of your three cases, and decides which overload to take, and what conversions to perform to make the call:

1. In case of `essai(n,z)` overload #1 wins, because it can be called with no conversion, vs. two conversions for overload #2
2. In case of `essai(c,z)`, overload #1 wins, because it can be called with a single conversion of `char` to `int`, vs. two conversions for overload #2
3. In case of `essai(n,p)`, both overloads require an equal number of conversions (two). Since there is no clear winner, the compiler considers the call ambiguous, and issues an error.

Comment: Personnal question : if the two function `void fexample (int)` and `void fexample (const int)` was defined, is there a compiler error?

Comment: @J.G [You cannot overload a function based on the `const` of the variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3682049/functions-with-const-arguments-and-overloading)

Comment: @J.G You would get a compile error on an attempt to override `int` vs `const int`. It would compile if you change `int` to `int&` and `const int` to `const int&` ([demo](http://ideone.com/eHzmke)).

Comment: @J.G `const` does not make a difference to the caller when passing by value, because copy semantic is used. You can call `foo(int)` and pass it `const int b = 5` because `b` would get copied anyway. Hence `foo(int)` vs. `foo(const int)` overload would be ambiguous. The situation with `int&` vs. `const int&` is different, because one cannot pass a `const` to a non-const parameter by reference. That's why the overload `foo(int&)` vs. `foo(const int&)` is unambiguous.

Answer (score 1):

Both

```
void essai (int, double);
void essai (double, int);
```

are valid overloads when you call `essai(n,p);` as one of the `int`s needs to be converted so it could convert either one.  Since you have two equal overloads the compiler gives up and should issue an ambiguity compiler error.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler doesn't know which data of `int` to convert to `double`.

You should convert it explicitly to call essai I:
`essai(n,(double)p);`

or to call essai II:
`essai((double)n,p);`