# Why should I not use `const` in this simple function?

Tags: c++, parameter-passing, constants

When learning C++, one of the first functions one gets for learning the concept of a function is something like

```
int add(int a, int b)
{
    return a+b;
}
```

Now I was wondering: Should I use the `const`-keyword here, or rather not, resulting in

```
int add(const int a, const int b)
{
    return a+b;
}
```

But would that make sense? Would it speed my program up, do some other important stuff, or just increase confusion?

Comment: It would certainly be confusing in the function declaration, where the `const` makes no difference (`void foo(int)` is exactly the same as `void foo(const int);`. But not in the definition. Of course, that is my opinion (hence comment, not answer.)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use of 'const' for function parameters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/117293/use-of-const-for-function-parameters)

Comment: Voted to close as **primarily opinion based**. I personally use top level `const` qualifiers on arguments, as a single convention applied throughout the code. I find that uniform conventions simplify things. Then you know that there's something special when the convention is not used. But that's a personal preference.

Comment: Even more opinion based is that seeing a parameter passed by `const` value helps gauge the competency of a programmer: I have found that useful at times.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf Kerrek's option 1 or 2? Personally, I prefer 3 over 2 over 1.

Comment: @Deduplicator: It would be 2, not used in pure declaration, except that I think header only modules are nice. :) There was once some discussion about that interface versus implementation thing. Apparently there are tools that are *much* happier when pure declaration is identical to implementation, and otherwise cause problems. Not sure which though. I can't remember.

Comment: @demonplus: I don't know, in the current case I am targeting a quite specific case, while the OP is targeting more advanced cases in his question. (imho)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

From the **caller's perspective**, both the first and the second form are the same.

Since the integers are passed *by value*, even if the function modifies `a` and `b`, the modified values are *copies* of the original and won't be visible to the caller.

However, from the **function implementer's perspective** there's a difference. In fact, in the second form:

> ```
> int add(const int a, const int b)
> ```

you will get a compiler error if you try to modify the values of `a` and `b` inside the function's body, as they are marked as `const`.

Instead, you can change those values if you omit the `const`.
Again, those modifications will *not* be visible to the caller.

Comment: This. You should add the the `const`in this case [is *not* part of the function's signature](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3682076/321013). That's the main reason *I* see for not including it for these simple functions, since it's not "really there" from the callers perspective but just an implementation detail: And for such a simple function its an unnecessary complication.

Comment: @MartinBa: Thanks for your comment. However, while in this super-simple case the const on the parameters in the function definition can be unnecessary, I think for more complex functions with more parameters marking them as const at the _implementation site_ can be helpful to catch bugs, e.g. making sure that those parameters are not modified by mistake and the modifications lost. I would omit the const at the declaration site (prototype) though, as it can be noisy/confusing for the caller.

Answer (score 7):

Using `int add(const int a, const int b)` means that you cannot modify the input parameters within the function body.

Perhaps the compiler can make some optimisations based on that, so it ought therefore to be never *slower* than the non-`const` equivalent. But I have never observed this effect in practice.

Passing `const` parameters can also increase the stability of your code base, particularly in a collaborative project.

All this said though, I find it too verbose, rather unnecessary, and would use `int add(int a, int b)`. *Very occasionally*, for particularly long functions, I exploit the fact that you can *declare* the function with non-`const` parameters, and *define* it with the parameters `const`.

Comment: It is the same as declaring const local variables, and we're OK with using those (not sure if it may inhibit copy elision for user defined types though.)

Comment: They're going to be copied either way, I see no optimisation possibility here but I'll leave that to the optimisation gods.

Comment: How can it increase the stability of my code base? My current style is: Either I have a pointer as input to my function (which is not constant), or a value, which then is declared const.

Comment: It can be reassuring in a particularly long function that the input parameters have not been messed about with.

Comment: @SomeWittyUsername Pff, the question is about passing by value. Comments about passing by reference are irrelevant here.

Comment: @juanchopanza The question is why not to use const when passing by value. And it's correctly answered by Mr.C64 below.

Comment: That would be a curious compiler which would use that local `const` as an optimization-tip instead of local analysis.

Comment: When you write some really long function (although not recommended), you may forget about some modification of parameter and use it wrongly. Using `const int a` will prevent such situation, trough the whole function you can be sure the `a` is `a`. Also when you refactor type from `int` to something more complex later, the `const` may help a bit the compiler then... But the `int` itself as the basic native type is probably that special case, where there's hardly any benefit, except of exercising "use const whenever possible".

Answer (score 7):

If you are actually struggling with correctness bugs in your codebase where `const` would have helped, then add `const`.

That said, there are related issues that you should consider. Top-level qualifiers of function parameters aren't part of the function type, so your function type is still just `int(int, int)`. (The qualifiers only affect the parameter variables in the function definition.) That means that any *declaration* of the function also ignores qualifiers, so `int add(int, int)` and `int add(const int, int)` and `int add(int, const int)` all declare *the same function*. So you have to decide on a policy for how you write header files. And now you have three essential positions you can take:

1. Always qualify in both declaration and definition. The upside is that this perhaps keeps code looking "consistent" (think copy/pasting when creating implementations). The downside is that the qualifiers have nothing to do with the interface, and are not at all enforcible (you can change the definition later!), so at best it's noise, at worst it's wrong.
2. Qualify in the definition, but not in the other declarations. The upside is that this communicates the interface correctly and you still get const checking in the definition. The downside is that some people might be confused by the discrepancies in spelling. (Just like people may be confused that a `static constexpr T foo;` class member can be defined with `const T C::foo;`.)
3. Don't qualify either. The upside is that it's consistent, clean, easy to remember and minimal. The downside is that you're missing out on correctness checks in your definition.

There's no right answer. If you're the codebase owner or project lead, you should decide based on what the biggest problems in your codebase and team are. (My personal position is to stick with (3) until you have a good reason to change.)

Comment: For the specific example in the question, qualifying the by-value parameters with const is actually confusing and misleading from the user perspective. The actual meaning of such qualification is that the copy is immutable which of course has nothing to do with the original object constness or lack of it.

Answer (score 1):

I feel like everyone is dancing around this part of the answer... 
It's true that using `const` will keep the function from modifying the value of your `int a` & `b` while inside the function. This can be extremely useful, so use it as you wish, of the compiler allows it. But, the function caller will never know about any changes to `a` & `b` once the function finishes. So even if `a` & `b` are changed, no one except the defined function will know their updated values.

```
int funcB(int a, int b)
{
    a = a+1;
    b = b*b;
    return a+b;
}

void funcA()
{
    int s = 5;
    int t = 6;
    int result = funcB(s, t);
    printf("%f + %f = %f", s,t, result);
}
```

funcA prints: "5 + 6 = 42"

`Const` protection is often used when passing values by reference, ie:

```
int function(const int &a, const int &b) {}
```

This passes a reference of `a` and `b` to the function (ie, does not make copies of `a` and `b` but passes only a memory address of that variable, aka: the handle). When passing a variable by reference, any changes made to the variable are remembered outside the scope of the function and can change the way your program runs. This is generally undesired behavior.
So if you rework `funcB` from above and pass by reference:

```
int funcB(int &a, int &b)
{
    a = a+1;
    b = b*b;
    return a+b;
}
```

funcA prints: "6 + 36 = 42"

If you add `const` correctness to `funcB`:

```
int funcB(const int &a, const int &b)
{
    a = a+1;
    b = b*b;
    return a+b;
}
```

I don't think the compiler will let you even do this since you would be explicitly trying to modify values that you've protected via `const`.

Another time when it may be really important to use const is when you're passing by pointer, instead of reference or copy...

```
int funcB(int *a, int *b)
{
    a = a+1;
    b = b*b;
    return a+b;
}
```

Unless you're a pointer expert, avoid passing pointers without const pretention. This func will likely attempt to iterate the index of your pointer arrays and you'd open yourself up to run time errors related to out of bound memory. You could accidently see memory from an entirely different program... but probably not.

Lastly, since you're just passing `int`, there's no practical need to pass by reference (which is done often to keep from adding complex data into memory because each non-reference or non-pointer pass to functions copies the value into memory for the life of the function being called) since the memory footprint of `int` is so small. Unless, you're working with specialized hardware that has extremely limited memory, then it may be useful; this won't apply to most standard computers and desktops made within the past 20 years, or smart phones.

Answer (score 0):

```
int add(const int a, const int b)
{
    return a+b;
}
```

Here const in used so that the function does not modify the original values of a and b by any chance. 
In the above example it does not make sense. But if it would have been an example like

```
int add(const int *a, const int *b)
{
    //*a = 10; //This will throw error. 
    return a+b;
}
```

In functions where objects,arrays or such data types are passed its a good approach to use const to avoid mutation of original data structure.

Comment: for compound types it is a good approach to use `const reference`, not merely const

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be truly const correct, then you should add it, but in reality all it will do is make you type and read more.

Nothing will go faster, and while it could mean that your variables go into another location in memory, it's unlikely to on most modern machines.

What it will stop you doing is accidentally assigning them values, but as they're local to the function, it's relatively unimportant.  What would matter is if they were references, as this demonstrates your intent to the caller to not change them.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `const` there if you like.

It is unlikely to speed up your program because any reasonable compiler can already see that no code path alters the value of `a` or `b` and make any optimisations it needs.

`a` and `b` are `int`, which are passed by value so making them `const` has no impact on the users of this function.

The only possible advantage is where your function is long and more complex and you want to avoid possible programming errors where the original values of `a` or `b` are changed during the function.

Answer (score 0):

If you will use const then you cannot modify the value of a,b. Thats why we don't use const.

Comment: Which I will not do in the two functions listed above. Thus I am asking...

Answer (score 0):

The primary purpose of constness is to provide documentation and prevent programming mistakes. Const allows you to make it clear to yourself and others that something should not be changed. Moreover, it has the added benefit that anything that you declare const will in fact remain const short of the use of forceful methods. It's particularly useful to declare reference parameters to functions as const references:

```
bool SomeFunction (const myObj& obj);
```

Here, a myObj object is passed by reference into SomeFunction. For safety's sake, const is used to ensure that SomeFunction cannot change the object--after all, it's just supposed to make sure that the object is in a valid state. This can prevent silly programming mistakes that might otherwise result in damaging the object (for instance, by setting a field of the class for testing purposes, which might result in the field's never being reset). Moreover, by declaring the argument const, users of the function can be sure that their object will not be changed and not need to worry about the possible side effects of making the function call.

moreover, The reason is that const for the parameter only applies locally within the function, since it is working on a copy of the data. This means the function signature is really the same anyways. It's probably bad style to do this a lot though. I personally tend to not use const except for reference and pointer parameters.

Answer (score 0):

as a law of thumb we are advised to use const as much as possible because we get a great help from the compiler so whenever we try to change a constant the mistake will be caught by the compiler; it's a good thing avoiding being caught in error-prones.

the second thing: a and b passed by value so they are created as local constants But as long as they are not changeable why we need copies??

- the good thing is to pass a const reference which means never change parameters and avoid copies (by value):

  ```
  int add(const int& a, const int& b) // now there are no copies of a and b in addition we cannot modify a and be
  {
      return a+b;
  }
  ```