# Operator overloading by reference return type in C++

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

In my beginners C++ textbook I keep seeing code like this (which works):

```
class Foo
{
   int& first();
   int first() const;

   double& operator[](int i);
   double operator[](int i) const;
 };
```

Possibly I missed the explanation somewhere but I am confused as to why this is okay. C++ does not support overloading by [return value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9568852/overloading-by-return-type) or by [const](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3682049/functions-with-const-arguments-and-overloading). Why is this code valid? Which function does the compiler call?

Comment: Read carefully the [second answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3682076/1870232) in your [second link](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3682049/1870232) . And allow me to duplicate this post :-D

Comment: C++ **does** support overloading by `const`.