# Functions const argument

Tags: c++, constants, overloading, declaration

I wander why c++ allows to declare this?

```
void f(int x);

int main()
{
     int x;
     const int y=0;
     f(x);
     f(y);
}

void f(const int x)
{
}
```

Why compiler allows you declare function with one signature, but define with another (cv qualifier added)?

Comment: It started off from C allowing to declare functions with no signatures at all.

Comment: Does it compile?

Comment: @KillzoneKid Yes it does or else it wouldn't be allowed :P

Comment: Almost dupe, just wrong way around: [Why does a function declaration with a const argument allow calling of a function with a non-const argument?](//stackoverflow.com/q/3681188)

Comment: of cource it does @KillzoneKid, VS2008, VS20017

Comment: Parameter cv qualifier is not a part of function signature. Also see this question: ["Functions with const arguments and Overloading"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3682049/functions-with-const-arguments-and-overloading)

Comment: @EduardRistimyan Sorry got confused by you saying both had different signatures

Comment: I think the reasoning here might be that whether or not something like an `int` parameter is declared `const` does not impact the _caller_ of the function in any way.  It just means that it can't be changed within the function body.  Something like that, anyway.

Comment: the parameter being declared as const is an implementation detail and actually not part of the function interface

Comment: @user463035818 Yes, I guess we're saying the same thing.  For an `int` parameter (as opposed to a pointer or a reference).

Comment: @PaulSanders uh yes I knew i missed some details, however, also for a pointer it doenst matter for the caller if the pointer itself is declared as const, or does it?

Comment: @user463035818 [Sure does](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strchr/).

Comment: @PaulSanders thats the pointee being const or not

Comment: @PaulSanders [for the pointer itself it think it doesnt matter](https://ideone.com/yV2lO0)

Comment: @user463035818 I don't understand that, sorry.  The point I was trying to make is that, in a function signature, there's a difference between declaring a parameter `char *` and `const char *`, as the link shows.

Comment: @PaulSanders i completely agree on that, but afaik its irrelevant whether the parameter is `int * const` or `int *`

Comment: @user463035818 Oh, I see.  If you put the `const` _there_, then yes.

Comment: Portability warning: This fails to compile under some compilers (e.g. Solaris C++ compiler). It is indeed kind of compiler bug, however if you need to deploy to Solaris and need to live with that compiler, you are out of luck and have to avoid this.