# Proper way of declaring `const` `boost::range`s

Tags: c++, boost, constants, boost-range

When using `boost::any_range`, what's the correct way of specifying that the underlying container (if any) shouldn't be modified?

E.g., with the alias

```cpp
template<typename T>
using Range = boost::any_range<T, boost::forward_traversal_tag>;
```

to declare a range that isn't capable of modifying the contents of the underlying container or "data source", should it be declared as

```cpp
const Range<T> myRange;
```

or as

```cpp
Range<const T> myRange;
```

?

I suspect the first version is the correct one. But is it guaranteed to keep the `const`ness of the container, if, for example, I apply any of the `boost::adaptors`?

**Edit**

From the [documentation](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_69_0/libs/range/doc/html/range/reference/concept_implementation/semantics/metafunctions.html), apparently the `range_iterator` metafunction "deduces" the `const`ness of the underlying container by declaring the range with `const T` instead of `T`. That is, `range_iterator::<const T>::type` is `const_iterator` (if the underlying container has such member type), instead of `iterator`, so the container can't be modified through this iterator.

Does that mean that `Range<const T>` also uses `const_iterators` to traverse the range?

Comment: `Range<const T>` and `const Range<T>` are two *very* different things. The first (`Range<const T>`) is a `Range` of constant `T`. The second (`const Range<T>`) is a constant `Range` of non-constant `T`. It's the same difference between e.g. `std::vector<const int>` and `const std::vector<int>`.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Except that `const Range<T>` might still be able to modify the underlying container, while `Range<const T>` may deduce the `const`ness (that is, use `const_iterator`s instead of `iterator`s) from the `range_iterator` metafunction. So, what exactly is a constant `Range`? One that uses `const_iterators` or one whose "wrapper" members don't change (but the underlying container might)?

Comment: `void f(const Range<T>)` doesn't do what you think. See [Top-level const doesn't influence a function signature](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17208570/1639256).

Comment: @Oktalist Yes, but that's beside the point. I'm asking whether a `const Range<T>` can modify the underlying container; I'm not asking how to overload the function based on the `Range` *object*'s `const`ness---which in principle could be independent of the underlying container's `const`ness. The function was just an example. I'll clarify.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: You can’t actually make `std::vector<const X>`, though.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the correct way to ensure that the values aren't modified is neither of those I mentioned.

From [Boost.Range's documentation](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_68_0/libs/range/doc/html/range/reference/ranges/any_range.html), we can see that `any_range` takes the following template parameters:

```cpp
template<
    class Value
  , class Traversal
  , class Reference
  , class Difference
  , class Buffer = any_iterator_default_buffer
>
class any_range;
```

I strongly suspect the way to declare a "const range" is to specify `const T` as the `Reference` type template parameter, although, surprisingly, I still haven't been able to find any explicit indication in the documentation that this is so.

So a const range could be declared as:

```cpp
template<class C>
using ConstRange = boost::any_range<C, boost::forward_traversal_tag, const C, std::ptrdiff_t>
```