# Template class + delegating constructor = fields not initialized? (clang-tidy)

Tags: c++, c++11, clang-tidy

I'm running clang-tidy 8.0 and I am getting the warning:

`constructor does not initialize these fields:`

when using a delegating constructor on a templated class. I want to know if this is a false positive I should suppress, or if indeed my code is wrong.

The example code in question is this:

```
template<typename T>
class A
{
public:
    explicit A(const std::size_t size) : 
        data_(nullptr),
        data_size_(size)
    {
        // ...
    }

    explicit A(const std::vector<T>& b) : 
        A(b.size())
    {
        // ...
    }

private:
    T* data_;
    std::size_t data_size_;
};
```

When running clang-tidy on this code:

`clang-tidy-8 --checks=* test.cpp`

I get, among other things:

```
warning: constructor does not initialize these fields: data_ [cppcoreguidelines-pro-type-member-init]
    explicit A(const std::vector<T>& b) : A(b.size()) {}
```

However, **if I remove the template from the class** and make it a normal class, then I don't get such error.

Is there something I'm missing when using delegating constructors on a templated class, or is this a bug in clang-tidy?

Thanks!

Comment: This is a bug: https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=37902

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's definitely a false positive. Your delegating constructor does indeed invoke another constructor which initializes both fields. However, I would consider just using a default initializer for `_data` in general anyways:

```
template<typename T>
class A
{
public:
    explicit A(std::size_t size) : 
        data_size_(size)
    {
        // …
    }

    explicit A(const std::vector<T>& b) : 
        A(b.size())
    {
        // …
    }

private:
    T* data_ = nullptr;
    std::size_t data_size_;
};
```

as that makes it even harder for anyone adding another constructor to forget to initialize `data_`. Unless, of course, there are some cases in which the member should remain uninitialized…

Also, note that the `const` on your `const std::size_t size` parameter in the first constructor of `A` [is quite pointless](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17208570/top-level-const-doesnt-influence-a-function-signature).

Comment: Ok, thanks! So I don't need to call the constructor using the template argument, like this?

A<T>(b.size())

Both options compile and both give the same error

Comment: @user1011113 I'm not sure what you mean. As far as I know, it's not possible to explicitly specify template arguments for constructor calls.