# Is the `const` keyword used in function declaration, or definition or both?

Tags: c++

```
void test(int& in);
void test(const int& in){

}

int main(){
 int a = 5; 
 test(a);
 return 0;
}
```

Above doesn't compile with a link error: `` undefined reference to `test(int&)' ``.

I have 3 questions on this:

1- Why do we get a link error?  is it because adding `const` to the definition makes it a completely different function? why would it work when not using references, i.e this works fine:

```
void test(int in);
void test(const int in){}
..
 int a = 5; 
 test(a);
..
```

2- Does `const` go in function declaration, or definition or both? Seems like
the behaviour is different if references are used.

3- Does the `const` keyword on an argument say *"the parameter passed to me should be a constant in the caller"* or *"this parameter is treated as a constant in this function scope, regardless of it being constant in the caller or not"*. I'm sure it's the latter but wanted to confirm.

Comment: [Related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17208570/top-level-const-doesnt-influence-a-function-signature)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In C++ the two functions:

```
void test(int& in);
void test(const int& in);
```

are TWO different, overloaded functions. The first binds to "writeable" integers, the second - to constant ones.

In your code:

```
int a = 5; 
test(a);
```

`a` is a modifiable object, hence `void test (int &)` is a better match from compiler perspective and it selects this function for a call.

The reason why you are getting linker error is that you declared but not defined this function.

In both cases below the `const` function would have been selected:

```
int const a = 5; 
test(a);
test(10);
```

Additionally if you only had `const` version declared as below, it would have been selected as well:

```
//void test(int &in);
void test(const int &in){}
..
 int a = 5; 
 test(a);
..
```

As for the second question in case of references - `const` goes both to declaration and definition as these are different functions.

With normal values there is NO difference between the two when declared:

```
void test(int in);
void test(const int in);
```

They refer to THE SAME function. The `const` version will prevent modification of the function parameter in function definition.

For the third one, when applied to references it means two things:

1. A reference will be passed to a function and not a copy for an object.
2. When accompanied by a `const` it promises to the caller not to modify referenced object and prevents the function from doing so.

Comment: how about using const without a reference? does it mean my second sentence?

Comment: I've explained that, haven't I?

Comment: You did, but just wanted to confirm, `const` in this case has nothing to do with the original value, it's only effecting the local scope inside the function.

Comment: Yes. In this case you are passing a copy to a function and that copy cannot affect the original object (subject to object design, in case of simple types its given) and cannot be modified inside a function.

Answer (score 2):

A function-definition is always also a function-declaration.

Thus, to differentiate them, the latter is often called a forward-declaration if it is not also a definition.

The function-signature used for overload-resolution derives from the function-declaration, and there are a few peculiarities in deriving it from the written source:

1. Top-level cv-specifiers on argument-types are discarded.
2. Top-level cv-specifiers on return-type are discarded if the type is not a class- or union-type. (A `struct` is a class-type.)

The function is not affected by these rules outside overload-resolution and matching declarations.

Applied to your examples:

```
void test(int& in);
void test(const int& in) { // const is not top-level
// The above two declarations are for different functions

void test(int in);
void test(const int in){} // const is top-level
// Equivalent declarations above
```

Answer (score 1):

A function definition is also a function declaration. Thus, you declare two overloaded functions, but only one function is defined, has a body.

The compiler choses the first function, since `a` is not const and the first choice is the exact match.

You get the linker error, since the first function has no definition, i.e. no body.

Answer (score -1):

It's best to do both, as the `const` keyword is intended to hint at the user that the variable will not be modified. I believe most compilers will treat a `const` type as a different type as well, so you'll have a compile error.